# Where can I find endpoint url for web service?

Tags: web-services, jboss, wsdl, jax-ws

After creating wsdl file for my web service using java, in the wsdl file soap:address location is set to  "REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL", how can I find the url to replace? ( I am using intellij 12 as IDE and JBOSS AS 4 as server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you developing this application then you can use localhost e.g.

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/TestWebService/HelloService"/>
```

where 8080 is JBoss's port
TestWebService is project you are developing
HelloService is wsdl file name or if you have changed mapping in web.xml then change this accordingly.

If you are going to deploy on server then change localhost to IP address of the server.